# In Paypal, how to set up shipping in one lump sum? Shipping field isn't processing correctly

Tags: html, paypal

I am setting up an online store. I would like to itemize products and charge shipping separately in one lump sum. I have created hidden input fields with names as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="My Product 1" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="80.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="2" />

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="My Product 2" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="3" />
```

etc

I am creating a hidden input field for the shipping cost as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="20" />
```

and a hidden input field for the tax amount:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="22" />
```

When the data is posted to the PayPal site, the items appear and the tax appears but the shipping cost is omitted. The field name "shipping" seems to be consistent with what is stated in the Paypal developers' guide.

Comment: can you link the relevant documentation?

Comment: @user3119171  If you specify shipping and shipping2 is not defined, this flat amount is charged regardless of the quantity of items purchased. 
This shipping variable is valid only for Buy Now and Add to Cart buttons. 
Default – If profile-based shipping rates are configured, buyers are charged an amount according to the shipping methods they choose.